# Is it possible to override method definition of native class with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, web-audio-api

I'm experimenting with Web Audio Api in TypeScript and having a small issue. I wanted to add some convenience methods to AudioParam's prototype to be able to use them on any parameter, but compiler failing saying "Property 'set' does not exist on type 'AudioParam'".

```
const ctx = new AudioContext()

AudioParam.prototype.set = function (value: number, at?: number, type?: number) {/*impl*/} // Here I'm getting an error on `set`
```

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You likely need to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to do this, but you should try to edit your post to be a [mcve] if you want more specific help.

Comment: Good point on merging, I'll try that, thanks

Comment: Ok, I have another question... Merging interface helped, just until I decided to add an enum and export it

`export enum RampTypes {...}`

Right after I've added `export` compilation started to fail again. If I remove `export` keywork everything is back to normal. So why exporting anything breaks the interface (or something else, idk)?

Comment: Once you use `export` you've created a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), which changes how TypeScript compiles.  I'm not sure how to help you without all your code, and this comment chain isn't the place for it anyway.  Please post a new question (or edit this one) with enough information for someone to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find the TypeScript way of doing this is in two parts:

1. First you need to do JS part (which is what you have above)
2. You need to tell the TypeScript compiler about the new method so it syntax checks downstream

I would suggest:

```
AudioParam.prototype.set = function (value: number, at?: number, type?: number) {
/*impl*/
}
export interface AudioParam {
    set(value: number, at?: number, type?: number);
}
```

Now the following should work and syntax check:

```
const myAudioParam = new AudioParam();
myAudioParam.set(1, 2, 3);
```